# XML element tags discarded while using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, xml-namespaces

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:orderMessageRequest xmlns:ns2="http://order.com.company.com">
<ns2:orderAck><orderNumber>25</orderNumber>
</ns2:orderAck>
</ns2:orderMessageRequest>
```

and xslt looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/entity/v1"
                xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1"
                 xmlns:ns4="http://order.com.company.com/">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="orderAck">
        <xsl:element name="orderAcknowledgement" >
            <xsl:element name="orderNumber"><xsl:value-of select="orderNumber"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am using xslt transformation on the above shown xml then it transforms with out xml elements, directly value without element tags, like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>25
```

How can I get this in xml format.? something like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns2:orderAcknowledgement      xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1">   

<orderNumber>25</orderNumber>
    </ns2:orderAcknowledgement>
```

Comment: This question has been answered many times already - for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284325/using-xls-to-convert-xml-to-text-file-just-returns-all-the-text-concatenated-ins/27284642#27284642

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I need to have element tags in output, tags should present along with value. that example is to get only the values in one line. I need some thing like reverse operation

Comment: Your first and main problem is that `<xsl:template match="orderAck">` does not match anything. It needs to be  `<xsl:template match="ns4:orderAck">`. What you see now is the result of all text nodes being copied by the built-in template rules that take over because you have no matching templates to override them.

Comment: is that ns2: or ns4:? because in input xml it is ns2:

Comment: It's the namespace URI that matters, not the prefix. In your input XML ns2 is mapped to ...company.com, and in your XSL it's ns4. So you need ns4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input XML, the `orderAck` is part of the namespace `http://order.com.company.com`. However, as mentioned in comments, in your XSLT you are currently looking for an element `orderAck` in no namespace, and that is different to one that is in a namespace.

Now, you should be able to do just this...

```
<xsl:template match="ns4:orderAck">
```

But the reason this will not match is not because the prefix is different, but because the namespace URI attached to the prefix is different in your XSLT. In your XML it is this...

```
http://order.com.company.com
```

But in your XSLT it is this

```
http://order.com.company.com/
```

The `/` at the end makes them different. (They are URIs, not URLs).

Also note, when you create the `orderAcknowledgement` using `xsl:element`, you are also not specifying the namespace, so you will not get the output you want, because you do want `orderAcknowledgement` to be in a namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/entity/v1"
                xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1"
                 xmlns:ns4="http://order.com.company.com">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:orderAck">
        <xsl:element name="ns3:orderAcknowledgement" >
            <xsl:element name="orderNumber"><xsl:value-of select="orderNumber"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again note it is the URI that is important, not the prefix. `orderAcknowledgement` is in the namespace `http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1` as required. If you really wanted `ns2` you could change the prefixes around. Also note, you don't really need to use `xsl:element` in these circumstances. Just write out the element as normal.

Try this XSLT too...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/entity/v1"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1"
                xmlns:ns4="http://order.com.company.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ns3 ns4">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:orderAck">
        <ns2:orderAcknowledgement>
            <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="orderNumber"/></orderNumber>
        </ns2:orderAcknowledgement>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please read up on namespaces. For example try http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html and http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/index.html.

Comment: thanks. I have one more question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971750/copy-all-xml-elemwnts-excluding-matched-element-root-name-using-xslt

Answer (score 1):

You have made the two most common XSLT beginners' mistakes and combined them.

Firstly, you've ignored the fact that your input elements are in a namespace, and they won't match the template rules or path expressions in your stylesheet unless you qualify the element names with a prefix.

Secondly, you've overlooked that if there's no template rule to match an element, the default rules kick in, and the default rules work their way down the tree to the text nodes, and then output the text nodes.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971750/copy-all-xml-elemwnts-excluding-matched-element-root-name-using-xslt