# Copy all xml elements excluding matched element root name using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation, xml-namespaces

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:VendorMessageRequest xmlns:ns2="http://order.com.company.com">
<ns2:purchaseOrder>     
<assignedTo>   
    <firstName>firstnm</firstName>
    <lastName>lstnm</lastName>
</assignedTo>
</ns2:purchaseOrder>
</ns2:VendorMessageRequest>
```

using XSLT as:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/entity/v1"
                xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1"
                 xmlns:ns4="http://order.com.company.com">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:purchaseOrder">
       <xsl:element name="ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder" >
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                 </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output coming as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1">
<ns2:purchaseOrder xmlns:ns2="http://order.com.company.com">
firstnmlstn</ns2:purchaseOrder>
</ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder>
```

and expecting output XML as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:someOtherPurchaseOrder xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1">
  <assignedTo>
      <firstName>firstnm</firstName>
      <lastName>lstnm</lastName>
    </assignedTo>
</ns2:someOtherPurchaseOrder>
```

=================
I am expecting the xml as shown above where matched element name(purchaseOrder) should be replaced with some other name(someOtherPurchaseOrder). and all the elements inside that matched element node should be copy to under changed element name.

i.e copy everthing and change the element node name.

Comment: Is that the actual XSLT you are using? You have an `xsl:template` nested within another `xsl:template` which is not allowed, and should cause an error. Also, as explained in a previous question, the namespaces are different. In your XML it is `http://order.com.company.com`, but in your XSLT it is `http://order.com.company.com/` so the template won't match anything anyway. Would it be possible to edit your question to correct this errors? Thank you!

Comment: @Tim: Sorry that was my typo mistake, I have just changed the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template that matches `purchaseOrder` you create a new element, which is what you require, but you also do `xsl:copy` which will copy the existing `purchaseOrder` element, which is not what you require, so you can remove the `xsl:copy` here.

```
<xsl:template match="ns4:purchaseOrder">
   <xsl:element name="ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You then do `xsl:apply-templates` to select the children, which is good, but you don't have any other templates in your XSLT to match them. This means XSLT's built-in templates will apply, and all these will do is output the text, but not any elements themselves.

You can solve this by adding the [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This, however, will copy the root `VendorMessageRequest` element too, so you would need to add a template to skip over that.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/entity/v1"
                xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1"
                 xmlns:ns4="http://order.com.company.com"
                 exclude-result-prefixes="ns2 ns4">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:VendorMessageRequest">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:purchaseOrder">
       <xsl:element name="ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to your comments, if you are getting an unused namespace declaration still present in your output, try this XSLT instead....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/services/entity/v1"
                xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1"
                 xmlns:ns4="http://order.com.company.com"
                 exclude-result-prefixes="ns2 ns4">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:VendorMessageRequest">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns4:purchaseOrder">
       <xsl:element name="ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that worked well. One problem here is that, namespace has been applied to all the children nodes, which is not required. like <assignedTo xmlns:ns2="http://order.com.company.com"><firstName>firstnm</firstName>.... Because, later I need to Unmarshall that xml.

Comment: @David, try without the `copy-namespaces="no"`.

Comment: we are using <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"> already. even I have added for <xsl:element name="ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder" >. No improvement

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaGf is Tim's suggestion, result is `<ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/services/dataobject/v1">     
   <assignedTo>   
      <firstName>firstnm</firstName>
      <lastName>lstnm</lastName>
   </assignedTo>
</ns3:someOtherPurchaseOrder>` which looks fine

Comment: That is true, but for me it applying namespace to all of the children, don't know why. Does other xsl template matches in the same xslt  effect this?

Comment: Even if the xmlns:ns2 declaration is present, it is not being used, so it doesn't actually make a difference. The XML is semantically the same as without it. `assignedTo` and its children are still in no namespace.

Comment: I've just noticed you've tagged your question `xslt 1.0`. `copy-namespaces` is only available in `xslt 2.0`. I've amended my answer to give an alternate approach though.